# How to display multiple records of mysql in java

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

So at the moment I have a class called MySqlConnection with this code inside it

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;

public class MySqlConnection {

    public static void Connection() throws Exception {

        // Accessing driver from the JAR file
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        // Creating a variable for the connection called "con"
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Friends", "John", "John123");
        // jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_record --> This is the database
        // root is the database user
        // root is the password

        // Here we create our query
        PreparedStatement Statement = con
                .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY first");

        // Creating a variable to execute query
        ResultSet result = Statement.executeQuery();

        while (result.next()) {

            System.out.println(result.getString(1) + " " + result.getString(2));

        }

    }

}
```

When I run this, it displays all the results at once in the Eclipse IDE.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSERt.png

How do I make it display all the results in a separate window?

Comment: Please elaborate on, `"... in a separate window"`. What *exactly* are you trying to do? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I would like the results to appear in a pop up window. I have tried using jpane, but it only displays one result at a time. and I have to click "ok" to see the next result.

Comment: It is good that you are posting your code, but your code is almost completely unrelated to the problem you are having. It doesn't matter where the values come from (SQL, a list, ...). So omit unneeded parts to make the question easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JTable on the JFrame to show the data in tabular format on a window. You can find examples on Internet about using JTable.

Comment: I'll give you a 1+ for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JTable. Here is my version

```
public class JResultTable extends JTable {
  public DefaultTableModel dataModel;
  ResultSet rs;
  public void init_model(){
  dataModel=new DefaultTableModel();
}

public void add_data() throws SQLException {
    String colNames[];
    ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData=rs.getMetaData();
    int colCount=rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
    colNames=new String[colCount];
    for(int i=1;i<=colCount;i++)
            colNames[i-1]=rsMetaData.getColumnName(i).toUpperCase();
    dataModel.setColumnIdentifiers(colNames);
    while(rs.next())
    {
        String[] rowdata=  new String[colCount];
        for(int i=1;i<=colCount;i++)
                rowdata[i-1]=rs.getString(i);
        dataModel.addRow(rowdata);
    }
}



JResultTable(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    super();
    init_model();
   this.rs=rs;
    add_data();
    setModel(dataModel);
 }
}
```

Ex- JResultTable mm=new JResultTable(rs)// rs is the resultset. Column Names will automatically become table headers (ResultSetMetaData)
add this mm to a panel or frame.